# How to detect silence on line-out/headphone using C#?

Tags: c#, audio

I have a scheduler that plays music from different sources. I'd like to write a small program to detect silence on line-out and sends an alert by e-mail. I'm using visual studio 2008 C#. Can someone give me directions on what audio library I can use or even show me some sample codes? (I can use C if there's a need to.)

Answer (score 0):

[This library](http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/) might prove useful.  My suggestion would be to use `waveIn`, and the analyze the samples you get.

You should configure your 'line in' so it is getting 'total mix' from the soundcard - most of the modern soundcards have that option.

Comment: op is asking for line-out, not line-in.